# What's the difference between "mind" and "spirit"?

Tags: word-difference

For creating a paper about personal development in German, I use some English studies. I often find the words "mind" and "spirit" which have an identical German translation in online dictionaries. How can I best describe the difference?

Comment: I assume that German translation is "geist", right?

Answer (score 5):

The common thing between the two is they describe a nonphysical part of a person. Now lets define each to get the difference.

Usually when you say "**spirit**" you are referring to the attitude of a person. It describes emotional things like motivation, courage, enthusiasm, etc.

"**Mind**" on the other hand describes the intellect and intelligence. The part of a person that has sense and logic and is not driven by emotions. The part that processes and memorizes things.

Answer (score 1):

If you have another translated word for the noun *soul*, I think it could best describe the noun *spirit* as they are often times synonymous.

According to Oxford Online Dictionary [mind](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mind) is defined:

> The element of a person that enables them to be aware of the world and
>   their experiences, to think, and to feel; the faculty of consciousness
>   and thought: *a lot of thoughts ran through my mind*.

You use [Holy Spirit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/holy-spirit?q=holy+spirit) for the third person of the Trinity, not Holy Mind.

You use [spirit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spirit) when you refer to the non-physical part of a person manifested as an apparition after their death. You don't use *mind* for this context.

*Mind* enables you to think and feel and is closer to your brain's logical function, but *spirit* is closer to your emotions (mood) and character (attitude).

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Answer (score -1):

According to my dictionary, spirit means "The inner part of a person that includes the feelings, thoughts and character."

According to my knowledge, our **feelings** (e.g. the feeling of love or hate, or hurt, etc.) are brought about by the heart, our **thoughts** are brought about by the mind or brain, and our **character** is brought about by both the mind and heart. For whatever we think or feel is portrayed physically; that is character.

For example, if a person is good, people will see his good character traits, and if a person is bad, people will see his bad character traits.

Comment: Which dictionary are you citing?